# Write a method that counts how many words begins with the letter "A"

Tags: java

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] fruits = new String [5];

    fruits[0] ="APPLE";
    fruits[1]="FIG";
    fruits[2]="GRAPE";
    fruits[3]="PEAR";
    fruits[4]="APRICOT";

    System.out.println(countA(fruits)+" word(s) begins with an \"A\"");
  }

  //Write a method that counts how many words begins with the letter "A"
  /** @param s is the current array

*  @return the number of words in s that begin with "A"
*/

public static int countA(String[] s){

  }
}
```

This is the whole programming code
and in it there are references.I want to solve this using java only.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: so, what is stopping you?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I need a way to solve this problem

Comment: well, you can have a look at `String#chatAt` method. Iterate over your string array, increment your counter  if the first character (at index 0) is equal to "A" and return the counter at the end.

Comment: Only 'A' or also 'a'?

Comment: "I need a way to solve this problem". That's really not what we (are supposed to) do here. You should try something yourself, show some effort at solving the problem. Then you show us your attempt, and tell us how it worked or not worked, and we can help you figure out what might be wrong with your attempt. Possibly even show you a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can stream the array and count elements after filter.

```
Arrays.stream(fruits).filter(s -> s.startsWith("A")).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int countA(String[] s){
    int result=0;
    for (int i =0 ; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i].startsWith("A")) result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage [cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) with code-only answers. Also please don't answer questions where the OP haven't really tried anything or put in some effort. Please [read more about how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int countA(String[] s){
    int x = 0;
    for(String y : s){
        if(y.startsWith("A")) x++;
    }
    return x;
  }
```

Comment: Please don't encourage [cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) with code-only answers. Also please don't answer questions where the OP haven't really tried anything or put in some effort. Please [read more about how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My bad. Next time I will start with "What have you tried so far?". Now I know why. Tnx.